# c# confusing on loop

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0

```
MessageBox.Show(urls[m]);
```

of the code below it show 16 time like a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,c,c,c,c,d,d,d,d  how can i add 4 non duplicate to urls[m].  My code is purpose to swlwct url from data base to open on 4 different browser1 browser 2 ..  but on browser show the same URL

```
namespace tabcontrolweb
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

         }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string MyConString = "SERVER=192.168.0.78;" +
                 "DATABASE=webboard;" +
                 "UID=aimja;" +
                 "PASSWORD=aimjawork;" +
                 "charset=utf8;";
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
            MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            MySqlDataReader Reader;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT  urlwebboard FROM `listweb` WHERE `urlwebboard` IS NOT NULL AND ( `webbordkind` = 'เว็บท้องถิ่น' ) and `nourl`= 'n' order by province, amphore limit 4 ";
            connection.Open();
            Reader = command.ExecuteReader();


            string[] urls = new string[4];
            string thisrow = "";
            string sumthisrow = "";

            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                thisrow = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    thisrow += Reader.GetValue(i).ToString();


                    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\file.txt", thisrow + " " + Environment.NewLine);
                    sumthisrow = Reader.GetValue(i).ToString();

                }

                for (int m = 0; m < 4 ; m++)
                {
                    urls[m] = sumthisrow;
                    MessageBox.Show(urls[m]);          
                }

                webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(urls[0]));
                webBrowser1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                webBrowser2.Navigate(new Uri(urls[1]));
                webBrowser2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                webBrowser3.Navigate(new Uri(urls[2]));
                webBrowser3.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                webBrowser4.Navigate(new Uri(urls[3]));
                webBrowser4.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;


            }



            connection.Close();


        }
```

Comment: What you've posted doesn't make any sense. Can you edit it to include an actual question? Like something other than source code?

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand this code:

```
for (int m = 0; m < 4 ; m++)
{
   urls[m] = sumthisrow;
   MessageBox.Show(urls[m]);          
}
```

Why are you inserting in urls[m] the same value?
Bear in mind that in the previous loop the variable *sumthisrow* will keep only the last value just like:

```
sumthisrow = Reader.GetValue(Reader.FieldCount - 1).ToString();
```

---

**EDIT**: Also consider using a StringBuilder for creation of *thisrow* variable.

---

**EDIT 2**: Put your disposable objects into a using statement.